# codeigniter 3 inline method call

Tags: php, codeigniter, class, methods, continuous-integration

In CI 2, we could initialize a class and call on one of its methods (or properties) with a single line of code.

E.g., $val = $this->load->library('some_library')->some_method($data);

However, it seems that CI 3 has removed this feature.

I am migrating a CI 2 app to CI 3 and the original app uses a couple hundred of these "inline" references. Does anyone know if there is a clean and efficient workaround for this so that I can continue my update without separating these references into 2 lines?

Comment: can you please show, where this is documented? I just checked https://codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/creating_libraries.html and it seems you need to load your library 1st and then you call its function...

Comment: I'm not sure it was ever officially documented. I saw it in an announcement from CI about features in the new release. Perhaps it was never officially documented but it was a feature integrated into v 2 that no longer exists in v 3.

Comment: Have a look at system/core/loader.php and check the code for function library(), _ci_load_library() and related for both Ci. 2.0 and 3.0 maybe you find there what you are looking for...

Comment: I will. I actually just spent the day updating the app, converting all the inline references to the standard method but I'm still interested in why it was removed (or never documented?); it was a handy feature sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

load the library first and call with the method():

```
$this->load->library('some_library');
$this->some_library->some_method();
```

Object should  be in lower case

Comment: I believe you are misunderstanding the question. I am aware of the standard method of performing this task but in CI 2, we could load a class And it's method in a single line of code ( e.g.,$this->load->library('some_library')->some_method() ) but CI 3 seems to not allow this. So, if that's the case, I would need to load the class first ($this->load->library('some_library')) and then call its method ($this->some_library->some_method()) as in your example. I'm inquiring if there is a workaround that makes it possible to load a class and call its method in a single line, like we could in CI 2.

Comment: I din't get any such way where u can load and call the method in single line. but u can use the alternative where u can achieve not like what inline do but something different. If you prefer to set your own class names you can pass its value to the third parameter:

$this->load->library('Yourlib', NULL, 'my_lib');

// Yourlib class is now accessed using:
$this->my_lib->method();